# CGContextDrawPDFPage memory leak

Tags: ios, ipad

Hello here is my code for drawing pdf in CATiledlayer

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{

         CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
         CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));
         CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, layer.bounds.size.height);
         CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
         CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(myPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, 0, true));
         CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, myPageRef);
 }
```

All is well but i got memory leak warning in following line

```
     CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, myPageRef);
```

Here myPageRef is CGPDFPageRef

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had download the code from github and make some R&D and found that,

I forgot to release `CGPDFPageRelease(myPageRef)` in `dealloc` method of my TiledView..

and after writing this code my memory leak solved....

```
 // Clean up.

 - (void)dealloc {
     CGPDFPageRelease(myPageRef);   
     [super dealloc];
 }
```

Comment: You should only do that if you retained it at some point. But if you're just doing `CGPDFDocumentGetPage`, you get an autorelease object and therefore you shouldn't release it. (Obviously, if you retained it, then of course you _must_ release it as suggested in this answer).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903182/cgcontextdrawpdfpage-memory-leak-app-crash

Answer (score 3):

Calling

```
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh); 
CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

before `CGContextDrawPDFPage` solved a similar problem of mine.

Credits goes to this answer of Johann:
[CGContextDrawPDFPage taking up large amounts of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975240/cgcontextdrawpdfpage-taking-up-large-amounts-of-memory/4225998#4225998)