# VFR Reader crashes in IOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, vfr-reader

I am using vfr/reader in my application for reading pdf files. It was working fine in IOS 6.1. But crashes when trying to run in IOS 7, the app crashes stating EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 1 while executing CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, _PDFPageRef); for a particular page everytime.

I've googled and came to know that the same issue was also raised when the ios 6 was released. I don't know how they solved the issue.

I also tried adding the following two lines before CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, _PDFPageRef) as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975240/cgcontextdrawpdfpage-taking-up-large-amounts-of-memory), but it doesn't helped solving the bug.

CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);

As I am a newbie to the Iphone application development, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Abilash.G

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue, I have tried many things but nothing works...
For now I settled with changing the pdf itself, removing the pages where the crash occured.

I thought it may have something to do with some deprecated CGContext functions in iOS7 (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGContext/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextShowGlyphs) but as far as I can see VFR Reader doesn't use those...

Comment: Anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: I've sent a Bug Report about 2 weeks ago, today they replied saying it's a Duplicate report, meaning they already know about it.

Now all that remains is a fix in the near (?) future...

Comment: great . Been trying to do find a fix for this but it is definitely ios7 related. Works fine on ios6.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on simulator with iOS 7.1, no solution atm..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested with XCode 5.1 Developer Preview in iOS 7.1 and it seems they have fixed the issue. 
No crash, works as it should. :)

Comment: Well, nobody knows for sure...
I'm guessing about 5-6 weeks maybe.
That's about how long XCode 5 Developer Preview was available before the stable release.

Comment: Yeah no one will know for sure. Oh well , just need to wait.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in iOS 7.

You should file a bug report with Apple and provide them with the PDF file that is causing the crash.

Comment: Anyone still encountering that issue?

Comment: yes, i found it. I just open a bug report with apple, but apple close it because it was a duplicate... i think that just know the problem..hope that apple fix it in iOS 7.0.4

Comment: 7.04 is out. Trying it out.